# Array sort keys numerically help

Tags: php

```
$test1[2] = "one";

$test2[1] = "two";
$test2[3] = "three";

$test = $test1 + $test2;

print_r($test);
```

I've used the array union operator but when i print the array it is in the wrong order.

```
Array ( [2] => one [1] => two [3] => three )
```

How do i sort the keys numerically in the array?; so i get the below result.

```
Array ( [1] => two [2] => one [3] => three )
```

Comment: By the by... did you try to research this on php.net? http://us.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=sort+array&scope=quickref

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a [number of options](http://php.net/manual/de/array.sorting.php), depending on the outcome you're after. Simplest is `ksort`:

```
$test1[2] = "one";

$test2[1] = "two";
$test2[3] = "three";

$test = $test1 + $test2;
ksort($test);
print_r($test);
```

See the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ksort.php

Answer (score 5):

Try ksort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

```
print_r($test);
ksort($test);  // (sorts in place)
print_r($test);
```

Answer (score 3):

> How do i sort the keys numerically in the array?

[`ksort()`](http://php.net/ksort)

---

<sup>Please, please, please take the time to look through the wealth of documentation (not just on array sorting functions), on php.net, before asking here. You'll more often than not find that we've not only documented the functions and what they do, but given you nice examples to demonstrate the usage and even make note of quirks, intricacies and special considerations.</sup>